# JSP resolve using DXA application in Tridion 9.5

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9.5, jsp

We have created a Page Template with an extension jsp and added Page view name in the template Page metadata. Component Presentations based on this Component Template will be Published as a Dynamic Component, in the Component metadata added entity view name. Component as multimedia links with associated schema and added component in page with above created Page template

added corresponding model and Page in Java backend. We are able to publish the JSP page in Tridion 9.5 but couldn't able to resolve. Is there any limitation on Tridion side for jsp includes?

Comment: When you say you aren't able to resolve - what does this mean exactly? Are you getting your page and the include is failing or is the include page itself not resolving? If the latter - what are you getting instead? 404 or something else?

Comment: I was getting error-404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DXA assumes that Pages (Page Templates) have a .html file extension in CM.
To the outside world, this file extension is usually suppressed (so-called extensionless URLs), but it will resolve if you do explicitly use the file extension in the URL.

Obviously, even though the (implicit) file extension is .html, this doesn't mean that these are static HTML pages; it just triggers an MVC flow using a Controller and View to render the HTML dynamically.

So, yes, DXA doesn't work with Page Templates which have a different file extension that .html.
If you really want to use JSP pages in your implementation, you should put them in your web app.